# How to generate unique loopback IPv6 address in Python?

Tags: python, ipv6

I need to be able to generate a unique IPv6 loopback address that I can use to for communication between processes within the host but not outside of it.

For IPv4 I found:

```
>>> import random, ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address('127.0.0.1') + random.randrange(2**24 - 2)
IPv4Address('127.23.181.175')
```

Is there is an analogue for IPv6?

Comment: IPv6 has a single loopback address (`::1`), while IPv4 has a range (`127.0.0.0/8`) of 16+ million addresses.

Comment: What is the reason for this? Right now this looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 only has a single loopback address: `::1`. This is detailed in [RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Section 2.5.3 The Loopback Address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.3):

> 2.5.3.  The Loopback Address
>
> The unicast address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 is called the loopback address.
> It may be used by a node to send an IPv6 packet to itself.  It must
> not be assigned to any physical interface.  It is treated as having
> Link-Local scope, and may be thought of as the Link-Local unicast
> address of a virtual interface (typically called the "loopback
> interface") to an imaginary link that goes nowhere.
>
> The loopback address must not be used as the source address in IPv6
> packets that are sent outside of a single node.  An IPv6 packet with
> a destination address of loopback must never be sent outside of a
> single node and must never be forwarded by an IPv6 router.  A packet
> received on an interface with a destination address of loopback must
> be dropped.